# Random numbers and bubble sort

Tags: java, random, user-input, bubble-sort

I'm trying to write a little program that would allow the user to first enter a number from 9 to 18, to generate corresponding random numbers (that represent the radius), then to calculate the surface (circle) of each randomly-generated number, and finally to sort the results in descending order.

So far here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number from 9 to 18: ");
        int num9a18 = input.nextInt();
        if (num9a18 < 9 || num9a18 > 18) {
            System.out.println("This number is invalid!");
        }       
        int num;
        for (int i = 0; i < num9a18; i++) {
            num = randomInt(1, 6);
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
    }
    public static int randomInt(int small, int big) {
        double PI = 3.141592564; 
        int results = ((int) (Math.random() * (big - small + 1)) + small);
        return results*results*PI;
    }
}
```

Can you give me some tips because I'm kind of stuck here.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of tips you're looking for or need, exactly.

Comment: What does it do? An error output would be most helpful.

Comment: No need to declare PI by hand: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program will have compilation error due to `int` - `double` inconsistency

Modified your program to fix that, as well as the one that you probably is looking for.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number from 9 to 18: ");
        int num9a18 = input.nextInt();
        if (num9a18 < 9 || num9a18 > 18) {
            System.out.println("This number is invalid!");
        }
        double result;
        List<Double> results = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < num9a18; i++) {
            result = resultFromRandomRadius(1, 6);
            results.add(result);
        }
        System.out.println("................SORTING.................");
        Collections.sort(results);
        for (double res : results) {
            System.out.println(res);
        }
        System.out.println("..........................................");
        System.out.println("................REVERSING.................");
        Collections.reverse(results);
        for (double res : results) {
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }

    public static double resultFromRandomRadius(int small, int big) {
        double PI = 3.141592564;
        int results = ((int) (Math.random() * (big - small + 1)) + small);
        return results * results * PI;
    }
}
```

Note: I'm making use of auto-boxing feature supported since Java 1.5

Update: Updated the code to demonstrate reverse() as well

**Output:**

Enter a number from 9 to 18:

10

................SORTING.................

```
3.141592564
3.141592564
12.566370256
12.566370256
28.274333076
78.5398141
78.5398141
78.5398141
113.097332304
113.097332304
```

..........................................
................REVERSING.................

```
113.097332304
113.097332304
78.5398141
78.5398141
78.5398141
28.274333076
12.566370256
12.566370256
3.141592564
3.141592564
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! Now if I'd like to have the results in the opposite order, what would I change to the actual code? Thanks again!

Comment: After `Collections.sort(results)`, you can use `Collections.reverse(results);` to have them listed in the reverse order

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work. The're not sorted anymore when I use Collections.reverse(results);

Comment: Thanks for all that! For some reason that I don't understand, it doesn't work here. The sorting works perfectly but reverse makes the numbers randomly sorted.

Comment: make sure you are calling the reverse after calling the sort. Simply calling reverse means to reverse the direction in which elements were added to the list and not descending order

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't do! Thanks a lot spiderman! You're the best!

Comment: glad to see it helped you :)